# On a double integral

Tags: integration

I have difficulty dealing with the following integral:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2-2xy\cos\theta+y^2+h^2}\text{d}x\text{d}y$$

where $\theta$ and $h$ are constants.

What I've tried:
using polar coordinates to get:
$$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\sec\theta}r\cdot\sqrt{r^2-2r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta+h^2}\text{d}r\text{d}\theta$$
if $h=0$, I know that I can take $r$ out of the square root and calculate the integral of $\text{d}r$ first, but how can I deal with the $h^2$ term since it's not always equal to $0$?

Update: thanks to the below, I've tried out something new.

I first change the $\cos\theta$ in the question to be a constant $m\in[-1,1]$. So I just need to evaluate:

$$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\sec\theta}
\sqrt{(1-2\sin\theta\cos\theta)r+h^2}\text{d}r\text{d}\theta$$

Here's what I got:
$$\frac23\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{(\tan^2\theta-2m\tan\theta+1+h^2)^\frac32-h^2}{1-2m\sin\theta\cos\theta}\text{d}\theta$$

I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Note $dxdy=rdrd\theta$. With this, it will be easy to handle the integral.

Comment: @Aaron If $\theta$ is a constant unrelated to the polar coordinate representation of $(x,y)$, it may be best to represent it with another letter.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake when translating to polar co-ordinates - you need to choose a different variable to avoid clashing with the existing $\theta$, and in doing so your $\cos \theta$ term seems to have disappeared.

Ignoring that, though, the inner integral looks something like this:

$\int r \sqrt{a r^2 + h^2} dr$

where $a$ can be treated as constant within the integral. Notice that $\frac{d}{dr}(ar^2 + h^2) = 2ar$, and so a substitution of something like $u = ar^2 + h^2$ will solve it pretty quickly.

Once you evaluate that, the outer integral becomes a bit nasty, but it should also capitulate to a well-chosen substitution in the end.